# Using Redis Sentinel from c#

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis, redis-sentinel

I have a master-slave configuration with two slaves and three sentinels. If I try the commands with command-line everything is ok.
But I have some problems configuring it for C#.
I am using StackExchange.Redis library. But I don't understand what I should do in order to get/set the keys from the master. Should I manually find the master and then get or set the keys or does it do it autonomously? What is the best way to do it? Each time i want to get/set a key should I check who is the master?
For now I did only this and I left my the other code as it was with only one master.

```
private static string ServiceName = "mymaster";
private static string IP { get { return "127.0.0.1"; } }
private static int Port = 26379;

public static readonly ConnectionMultiplexer Connection = GetConn();
public static readonly IServer Server = Connection.GetServer(IP, Port);

public static ConnectionMultiplexer GetConn()
{
    try
    {
        // create a connection
        var options = new ConfigurationOptions()
        {
            CommandMap = CommandMap.Sentinel,
            EndPoints = { { IP, Port } },
            AllowAdmin = true,
            TieBreaker = "",
            ServiceName = ServiceName,
            SyncTimeout = 5000,
            AbortOnConnectFail = true,
            Ssl = false
        };
        var connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options, Console.Out);
        return connection;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ASLog.LogError(ex, 1);
        return null;
    }
}
```

where I have one of the three sentinels at port 26379. 
Sorry but I am a bit confused how to use this with C#.

Comment: Just four years and we can get it out of the box https://stackoverflow.com/a/64177201/1426685

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify or check for the master node, the library will choose the master for write operations.

Anyway all the methods have an optional [CommandFlags](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/CommandFlags.cs) parameters where you can specify where to execute an operation (DemandMaster, DemandSlave, PreferMaster, PreferSlave).

For example:

```
var cnn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379");
var db = cnn.GetDatabase();
db.StringSet("key", "value", null, When.Always, CommandFlags.DemandMaster);
var value = db.StringGet("key", CommandFlags.PreferSlave);
```

Comment: when i try to use `StringSet` it says `This operation has been disabled in the command-map and cannot be used: SETEX`..

Comment: Do you have any [`rename-command`](http://redis.io/topics/security#disabling-of-specific-commands) on redis.conf?

Comment: Why is he doing all this then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385075/redis-failover-with-stackexchange-sentinel-from-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: @thepirat000 Does the CommandFlags parameter handle master failover?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve mine by changing the CommandMap from Command.Sentinel as follows:

```
    var commands = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                    { "info", null }, // disabled
                    { "select", "use" },
            };
    sentinelConfig.CommandMap = CommandMap.Create(commands);
```

The error should disappear.