# StackExchange.Redis - Is it possible to prioritize Endpoints?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

My setup:

- 4 Windows servers
- A Redis Node and a Sentinel Process on each of theses servers
- The same webapplication deployed on each of these servers
- The webapplication connects to the redis servers via the StackExchange.Redis driver

Everything works great but I wonder if it is possible for read operations to always try to use the redis node that is locally available first. This would enhance performance quite a bit because there would be fewer hops for all read operations.

As far as I see one can prioritize slaves over masters für specific commands via the Command Flags property. **But is there a way to prioritize specific endpoints**?

PS:

Used DLL: StackExchange.Redis.StrongName@1.2.0.0

Redis Server Version: 3.2.100

EDIT:

Here is my connection code. The reason why I did not use the recommended Lazy getter is because I wanted to Connect/Reconnect on Failure of one of the nodes, which works very well with my solution.

```
internal class RedisConnector
{
    private readonly ConfigurationOptions _currentConfiguration;
    internal ConnectionMultiplexer Connection;

    internal RedisCacheStore Store;

    internal RedisConnector(ConfigurationOptions configuration)
    {
        _currentConfiguration = configuration;
        Connect();
    }

    internal IDatabase Database
        => Connection.GetDatabase(RedisCacheConfiguration.Instance.Connection.DatabaseId);

    internal IServer Server => Connection.GetServer(Database.IdentifyEndpoint());

    private void Connect()
    {
        Connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(_currentConfiguration);
        if (Connection == null || !Connection.IsConnected)
            throw new CacheNotAvailableException();
        Connection.ConnectionFailed += OnConnectionFailed;
        Connection.ConnectionRestored += OnConnectionRestored;
        Store = new RedisCacheStore(Database);
    }

    private void Reconnect()
    {
        if (Connection != null && !Connection.IsConnected)
            Connection.Dispose();
        Connect();
    }

    private void OnConnectionFailed(object sender, ConnectionFailedEventArgs args)
    {
        lock (_currentConfiguration)
        {
            if (_currentConfiguration.EndPoints.Contains(args.EndPoint))
            {
                _currentConfiguration.EndPoints.Remove(args.EndPoint);
                Reconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnConnectionRestored(object sender, ConnectionFailedEventArgs args)
    {
        lock (_currentConfiguration)
        {
            if (!_currentConfiguration.EndPoints.Contains(args.EndPoint))
            {
                _currentConfiguration.EndPoints.Add(args.EndPoint);
                Reconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, what do you mean by prioritize ?

Comment: is it prioritizing, the redis node with a rule such as try calling local redis instead of calling another one ?

Comment: The ConnectionMultiplexer manages my four endpoints. As far as I know the ConnectionMultiplexer looks through the available endpoints and chooses one when I issue a specific command (e.g. SET or GET). Now I would like the ConnectionMultiplexer to use one specific endpoint over others (if it's available). I understand I could iterate over the endpoints myself, but I figured that's what the ConnectionMultiplexer is for. So I was wondering if there is a way to keep that abstraction intact but maybe do what I want by way of configuring the ConnectionMultiplexer endpoints.

Comment: ok understood now, here is my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case.

Let say you have this case, 3VM with 3 apps & 3 redis instances.
[image]
The best option for APP runningin VM1 is to use Redis in VM1.
The best option for APP runningin VM2 is to use Redis in VM2.
The best option for APP runningin VM3 is to use Redis in VM3.

You can implements some rules like so :

```
private static Lazy<ConfigurationOptions> configOptions
    = new Lazy<ConfigurationOptions>(() => 
    {
        var configOptions = new ConfigurationOptions();
        configOptions.EndPoints.Add("x.x.x.1:6379");          
        configOptions.EndPoints.Add("x.x.x.2:6379");
        configOptions.EndPoints.Add("x.x.x.3:6379");

        configOptions.ClientName = "LeakyRedisConnection";
        configOptions.ConnectTimeout = 100000;
        configOptions.SyncTimeout = 100000;
        return configOptions;
    });



private static string getIP()
{
    var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            return ip.ToString();
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("ip not found!");
}


private static Lazy<ConfigurationOptions> getOptionsForIp(string myip)
        {
            var configOptions = new ConfigurationOptions();
            configOptions.EndPoints.Add(myip);
            configOptions.ClientName = "LeakyRedisConnectionDirectVM";
            configOptions.ConnectTimeout = 100000;
            configOptions.SyncTimeout = 100000;
            return configOptions;
        });


private static ConnectionMultiplexer conn;

private static ConnectionMultiplexer LeakyConn
{
    get
    {
        if (conn == null || !conn.IsConnected){               
            string myIP = getIP();

            conn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(getOptionsForIp(myIP).Value);
            if(conn == null || !conn.IsConnected){
                conn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configOptions.Value);
            }

        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

How to use this code:

```
 var db = LeakyConn.GetDatabase();
 db.StringSet(key, i);
 db.StringGet(key);
```

Comment: @ //conn = code here your private rules
How would this code look like? I mean I understand I could always remove all the endpoints other then localhost+master. Then I could maybe listen for a ConnectionFailed event in which case I could try the next endpoint. Is that what you are proposing or is there a better option?

Comment: A good practice is trying the "closer" server in term of region/ping/webaccess. This can be configured by yourself. If you have redis running in a same server than your apps, its good to use localhost rest first.

Comment: Well of course, but how can I accomplish that. As I said: Only giving the multiplexer two endpoints (localhost+master) would maybe work but I feel like that would be kind of dangerous. It would definitely be better if the driver automatically prioritizes the endpoints in the order I specify. I had a look into the StackExchange.Redis source and I could not find a reason to believe that the order of the endpoints matters for the `ServerSelectionStrategy`

Comment: So with your newest edit: It would connect only to the local endpoint. And in case the connection does not work it would go on to the other endpoints. This unfortunately does not provide a solution for situations when the local endpoint is not a master (in this case every WRITE operation would fail). I could of course manually look for the master. I will just test this out, if it is reliable enough.

Comment: yes of course, if you want to write you will need to pass the writes to the master. For read purposes you can offload your jobs to the slaves. Salvesa are only used for read purposes (even if redis permit to have writes to slaves, this is not safe / you will /can loose datas).

Comment: Yes, although the default setting for `slave-read-only` is true. Well okay, i wished there was a way to hook into the ServerSelection of SE.Redis, but it seems as if there is only the option to dynamically adjust the configuration.